# How is the statement T::x(y) ambiguous if T is a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, ambiguity, typename

I was reading the fact sheet at this url

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fkeyword_typename.htm

and I realized that I have no idea what type T::x could possible represent.  Here is a excerpt

```
template<class T> class A
{
  T::x(y);
  typedef char C;
  A::C d;
}
```

> The statement T::x(y) is ambiguous. It could be a call to function x()
>   with a nonlocal argument y, or it could be a declaration of variable y
>   with type T::x. C++ will interpret this statement as a function call.
>   In order for the compiler to interpret this statement as a
>   declaration, you would add the keyword typename to the beginning of
>   it. The statement A::C d; is ill-formed. The class A also refers to
>   A and thus depends on a template parameter. You must add the
>   keyword typename to the beginning of this declaration:

I would like to understand how there could be a variable y of type T::x, how would this work and what could this possibly mean?  What would the x be?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a warm-up to my full answer, consider the following:

```
template <typename T> void IterateOverContainer(T container) {
    /* Error! */
    T::iterator itr(container.begin());
}
```

Here, `iterator` is a type nested inside of `T`; for example, `std::vector<int>::iterator`.  To avoid ambiguities here, the `typename` keyword becomes necessary:

```
template <typename T> void IterateOverContainer(T container) {
    /* Now good! */
    typename T::iterator itr(container.begin());
}
```

Now this is "clearly" the name of a type (that's what `typename` means!), so it's clear that we want to declare a variable rather than call a function.

That said, with new C++11 features, you can sidestep this entirely with `auto`:

```
template <typename T> void IterateOverContainer(T container) {
    auto itr(container.begin());
}
```

Or, more clearly:

```
template <typename T> void IterateOverContainer(T container) {
    auto itr = container.begin();
}
```

Now, as to your question: how could `T::x(y)` ever declare a variable?  Well, due to a weird quirk of C, this is a perfectly legal variable declaration:

```
int (x);
```

It's the same as

```
int x;
```

So if we had something like this:

```
template <typename T> void IterateOverContainer(T container) {
    /* Error! */
    T::iterator(itr);
}
```

This could be interpreted as a declaration of a variable named `itr` of type `T::iterator`, or as a call to the function `T::iterator` passing `itr` as a parameter.  The use of `typename` disambiguates which one it is.

Interestingly, this provision for extra parentheses is the same reason that the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) exists.  I hope you never encounter it. :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like your account was made to answer this question :)

Comment: Just a few quick questions, if I define a class inside of another (x inside of Y) That would be type Y::x?  I think that lowercase x is what threw me off, I didn't realize it was a nested class if that what it is.  Also is  T::iterator itr(container.begin());
constructing a type, how else could that be interpreted? Sry for my ignorance on the topic

Comment: @rubixibuc- (Note that I updated my answer a bit before I got this message, so you may want to read the end my edit).  I'm not sure I get what you mean by "constructing a type;" can you clarify?

Comment: @templatetypedef Your edits answered that second part.  But is iterator a class definition nested inside of class type T?

Comment: @rubixibuc: It may be a class definition. Or it may be a typedef. It doesn't matter; what matters is that it is the name of a type. And the rules of C++ require that you use `typename` in templates so that it can know that it's a type name.

Comment: @templatetypedef sry but just one more :-(, the example where you are using auto, I though that auto is just defines a local variable (non extern, non static) what is it doing in this case.

Comment: @rubixibuc- The `auto` keyword has been repurposed to mean "figure out the appropriate type of this variable rather than having me tell it to you."  It's really cool!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first example here fully. As I see it, it is an ambiguity between a type declaration and a function prototype declaration, just like the Most Vexing Parse example, right? I don't see how this clarifies the original question, unlike the second part of your post. Please do let me know if I'm missing the obvious or making embarrassing errors.

Comment: @batbrat- The first part of my answer is showing off a more common case - a confusion between a function call and a variable declaration.  The more direct answer to the OP's question is in the second half.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, `T::x` can mean "The `x` type (perhaps a `class` or `typedef`) that is defined within `T`.  It could also mean "a pointer to the `T`'s member function `x`.

It's often possible for the compiler to figure out which is correct based on certain cues (did you write `T::x foo` or `void (T::*)() foo = T::x`?); Visual Studio does, and GCC used to (they stopped because, at the time, people would get their code to compile on GCC but not on Visual Studio).  The Standard requires `typename` to disambiguate the hard cases.